# changing iframe src

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have embedded a youtube video in my page.
and i need to change the video when i click on a link.
what i have done is i have changed the src of the iframe using jquery.
the src is changing,but the video is not appearing. is this the best approach ?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#clickme").click(function(){

 alert("hi");
 $("#myPlayer").attr('src','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M73UUllE39w&feature=g-vrec');

 });


 });

 </script>

 </head>
  <body>

 <iframe id="myPlayer" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ojQyhk5knx4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 <a href="#" id="clickme"> Click to change video</a>
```

can someone tell me what i m doing wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

If you check the YouTube EMBED code, their URLs are in this format: http://www.youtube.com/embed/Th3STX3gKX0

You most probably need to follow this principle instead of navigating to a YouTube video itself.

Comment: yeah,it worked. thanks. that was really a silly mistake.actually i have three videos in my page.is there anyway to load three videos like loading the second video after the first one is done..

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try and browse the **[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)** to see if that's possible